# Botpress send and get file from MS Teams

Tags: file, microsoft-teams, botpress

At first, to connect my Botpress bot with MS Teams, I followed these procedures from [Botpress MsTeams connection page](https://botpress.com/docs/channels/teams), but in this way, I can't send messages to the bot. I made some research and find out I need to publish my bot as an app. To solve this problem I created a trial version of the Microsoft 365 developer subscription

After that, I created an App with a bot from App Studio and now I have the choice to send the file to the bot but Botpress can't see the file and It can only see the texts. How can I send files to the user and get files from a user from the Teams app using Botpress?

Answer (score 0):

You can send and receive the files using bot. Please check [Send and receive files through the bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/bots-filesv4) also check [Example](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/56.teams-file-upload) for how to upload a file using bot.

Comment: Hello! This answer uses BotFramework to send and receive a file, I am searching for a solution with using Botpress :)

Comment: Could you please check this [docs](https://botpress.com/docs/advanced/configuration#how-to-save-logs-on-the-file-system), try if that helps. Also could you please share which document you are following?

Comment: In the end, I found out BotPress doesn't support sending files. I am writing a new service to stay between botpress and teams using BotFramework :)